# excel regular expression replace all commas in cell

Tags: excel

I'm wonder how to replace all commas in a a cell. Can be Excel, Open Office, or Google sheets

**here is the string**:
1 Central (CO, MT, NB, ND, SD, UT & WY),1 North Central (MI, MN, WI, IL, IN, OH, IO, & WV),All contacts

**I need it to produce**:
1 Central (CO | MT | NB | ND | SD | UT & WY),1 North Central (MI | MN | WI | IL | IN | OH | IO & WV),All contacts

Replacing all the commas inside the ( ) brackets

The closest I've gotten is

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A228, "\(([^\(]+?),([^\)]+?)(\))", "($1 | $2 )")
```

**which produces**

1 Central (CO |  MT, NB, ND, SD, UT & WY ),1 North Central (MI |  MN, WI, IL, IN, OH, IO, & WV ),All contacts

Any ideas? Probably something simple :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do these with the `SUBSTITUTE` formula:

Assume string is in cell `A1` then in `B1`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","|"),")|", "), ")
```

Input:

`1 Central (CO, MT, NB, ND, SD, UT & WY),1 North Central (MI, MN, WI, IL, IN, OH, IO, & WV),All contacts`

Output:

`1 Central (CO| MT| NB| ND| SD| UT & WY), 1 North Central (MI| MN| WI| IL| IN| OH| IO| & WV), All contacts`

Comment: Excellent! Works perfect! And I noticed there a 100+ cells that have the "All Contact, 1 Central..." first in the string. And its replacing the , with |.
Do I need to add another SUBSTITUTE or ?

Comment: Yes. Do: `SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","|"),")|", "), "), "|", ",", 1)`. Note the use is `1` to only change the first instance of a "|".

Comment: Thank you so much!